# Bar graph with standard errors from Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DataFrame that stores results from a regression, like this:

```
feats = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3']
betas = [0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
ses = [0.05, 0.03, 0.02]
data = {
    "Feature": feats, 
    "Beta": betas,
    "Error":ses
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It looks like this:

```
   Beta  Error Feature
0   0.5   0.05      X1
1   0.7   0.03      X2
2   0.9   0.02      X3
```

I want to make a graph coefficients for each feature, the height being "Beta" and the error line being "Error".

Is there a way to get this working in Matplot?

I have tried error plot but maybe did it wrong or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `plt.errorbar` as following (`matplotlib 2.2.2`)

```
plt.errorbar(data.Feature, data.Beta, yerr=data.Error, capthick=2, capsize=2)
```

If somehow the above line doesn't work for you, you can use this workaround

```
plt.errorbar(range(len(data.Feature)), data.Beta, yerr=data.Error, capthick=2, capsize=2)
plt.xticks(range(len(data.Feature)), data.Feature)
```

[image]